# Getting Program Counter value on ARM Cortex M series using C

Tags: c, arm, embedded

Is there any trick to write a function for ARM Cortex M series ICs that returns the PC value before function calling. Without using assembly language.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`__current_pc`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.kui0097a/armcc_chdfgfab.htm) intrinsic, e.g.

```
int main()
{
    printf("Current PC = %u\n", __current_pc());
    return 0;
}
```